# If row contains any values, multiply two cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want column S to multiply the value of column G and column R until the last row of my data set (The length of the data set varies). Does anyone know how to go about this? Currently, I am trying things like:

```
    Dim LastRow As Long, d As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    For d = 2 To LastRow
    If Range("U" & d).Value = "" Then Set rw.Columns("S") = rw.Columns("F").Value * rw.Columns("R").Value * 0.01
    Next d
```

But they don't work. It does not seem that difficult to me, but I still can't figure it out. I would really appreciate any help!

[image: Raw Data]

Comment: So, for each empty cells in "U:U" column, the corresponding (row) "S:S" should be obtained by that multiplication. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

Please, try using the next code. You did not answer my clarification question, so it works on the assumption that the column S:S is filled with the multiplication result **only for empty cells in column U:U**. If not an empty cell, a null string will be filled. If already there are values in S:S, which must be kept, please state that and I will adapt the code to keep them:

```
Sub FillSSColl()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngS As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("U" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row

  Set rngS = sh.Range("S2:S" & lastR)
  rngS.value = Application.Evaluate("=If(" & rngS.Offset(0, 2).Address(0, 0) & "= """"," & _
         rngS.Offset(0, -13).Address(0, 0) & " * " & rngS.Offset(0, -1).Address(0, 0) & " * 0.01,"""")")
End Sub
```

But your question meaning in words does  not match your code attempt...

If you want the code to calculate **if row contains any value**, as the title states, the code should be modified from `If(" & rngS.Offset(0, 2).Address(0, 0) & "= """","` in `If(" & rngS.Offset(0, 2).Address(0, 0) & "<> """","`. I tried following what I could deduce looking to your code.

**Edited**:

Please, try the version filling all S:S column for the U:U column filled range:

```
Sub FillSSColl_bis()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngS As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("U" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row

  Set rngS = sh.Range("S2:S" & lastR)
  rngS.value = Application.Evaluate(rngS.Offset(0, -13).Address(0, 0) & " * " & rngS.Offset(0, -1).Address(0, 0) & " * 0.01")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your comment! I tried both versions but they do not work. My wording can be the issue, that's a fair point. I want to S2 to multiply G2 and R2, S3 to multiply G3 and R3 and so on until the last row of my data set. "If" might be misleading, I was trying to say as long as the row contains any data, S should be "=G * R * .01"

Comment: @TbHxC Not clear at all what you wanted accomplishing... And I also cannot understand what "both versions" should mean. Anyhow, if you need the multiplication for all the range, I will edit the answer and place such a version. Still not sure what you want accomplishing and I do not dare to delete the existing one...

Comment: I inserted a screenshot in the OP, the column "Net split tot price" should be =G2 * R2 * 0.01 for Row 2, =G3 * R3 * 0.01 for Row 3 and so on. Does that make it any clearer? Sorry if I fail to bring my point across.